# Let $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \ $ be Lebesgue measurable .

Tags: measure-theory

If $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \ $ is Lebesgue measurable  function, then show that inverse image of a closed interval is measurable .

**Answer:**

Let $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \ $ be measurable .

Let $ I=[c,d] \ $ be a  closed interval .

Then , $ \ f^{-1} ([c,d])=\{x \in [a,b] : f(x)  \in [c,d]=I \} \ $

**But now I can not proceed .**

Is there any help ?

Comment: What's your definition of "measurable"… with the usual one the question is quite trivial (check Yannik's answer). So I doubt you use that one.

Comment: Lebesgue measurable

Comment: That's not a definition at all… How do you define "Lebesgue measurable"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is help. Read the definition of "measurable function".

Comment: I can not conclude

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean measurable w.r.t. the Borel sigma-algebras $\mathcal{B}[a,b]$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. By definition $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(B)$ is $\mathcal{B}[a,b]$-measurable for every $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Since your $I$ is a closed interval, it is contained in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and by measurability of $f$, $f^{-1}(I)$ is contained in $\mathcal{B}[a,b]$.